# Java open-source web framework

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm currently working on a project where the front-end has to be a mobile application or a website.I want the back-end to be in java.I want to use rest as communication between the front-end and back-end. My question is : Is there a java web framework that has some kind of user management (with maybe webservices to login and signup users). For example so that the login details can be send from the front-end to webservice and then would see if it's correct etc..

Comment: Where are you planning to maintain the user records, in your custom data store (ldap , db) or you want to leverage using exiting store like google accounts, open ids.

Comment: I believe most of the answers you will get will not be specific. There are three major rest frameworks in java, Jersey (based on Jax-rs spec), Restlet and Spring 3.0 (does not comply with Jax-rs). The easiest way to get started is using spring 3.0 Rest framework. You need to be comfortable with Dependency Injection and some other spring niceties, but to have a working copy you could just use spring roo and get it done within 15 mins.http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/27/roo-part-2/

Comment: The reason I say easiest is Spring Roo will expose your entities ( in this case user tables) as rest api and spring security module can add authentication framework on top of it without much coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Grails](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grails.org%2F&rct=j&q=grails&ei=7CJtTcLNJ5S-tgfE953gBQ&usg=AFQjCNGIgpW3nOFVxqBZifqp9XE4d7Xd1Q&cad=rja) which has a rich catalog of plugins, including the [spring security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) which should do as you require without having to write much code.

If you must use Java only, then Spring MVC with the [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) (which also includes free hosting).

Comment: Ohw i forgot to mention, this is a project for school, and it should be free, so this is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Struts, Spring MVC, JSF are some common examples which are widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.0 MVC would be a good place to start for the back-end. This will give you the basic REST web service support. You can probably tie in spring security to get some basic user management also

Answer (score 0):

For REST I'd look at [jax-rs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS)([RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html)) or [sitebricks](http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/)

Comment: jax-rs is something i'm familiar with, but i was wondering if there wasn't some kind of framework with a user management system too , or easy to add

Comment: I know you want java, but that best at that sort of thing is rails which you can use from jruby. Grails has some good plugins too, but still not java.

Answer (score 0):

[Lift](http://liftweb.net/) (Scala based web framework) has a nice set of pre-built user management support

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CUBA Platform. It has pretty strong back-end and admin UI plus generic REST-API with Google Polymer UI for custom mobile applications or web sites. http://github.com/cuba-platform/cuba